# Create a Junit test case for a method which contains a call to another method from different class which calls to a different method of the same class

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am new to java and Unit testing. I am facing a problem in writing a unit test to one of the test methods. Can you please help me with this.

ClassA:

```java
Class   classA{ 
    /*......*/
    classB  method1_ClassA(parameters){
        /*.....
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....*/
        String  some_Identifier =   method2_ClassA(parameters)

    }
    private String  method2_ClassA(parameters){
        /*contains call to the database*/
    }
}
```

ClassB:

```java
Class classB{
    /*.....*/
}
```

ClassC:

```java
Class   classC{
    /*.......*/
    public  classB  method1_ClassC(parameters){
            classA  obj_ClassA  =   new classA();
            return  obj_ClassA.method1_classA(parameters);
    }
    /*.......*/

}
```

I am trying to do Unit Testing to the classC. One of the methods in ClassC calls a method of class A. I tried to mock this method, which is method1_classA. But this method has a call to another method which is present in the same class. Can somebody please help me on how to create a unit test for classC.

Comment: Show what code have your write. Seriously, try and may be yourself can write test.

Comment: If the class that I want to test has a method which makes a reference to an external data I could have used mockito.when(class_Name.method_Name()).thenReturn(mockMethod_Name()). But I dont know how to do it here. 
Can you please provide some references on how to tackle this problem

Comment: Dont put information into comments; update your question instead. The crucial point anyway: if you MOCK a method, then it absolutely does not matter what that method would be doing in reality. If you mock foo() you replace the "real" foo() with something that does nothing. Meaning: if foo() calls other methods on the same object, or a different one ... all of that ... is not of interest ... because you create MOCK.

Comment: @GhostCat My mock tests are failing because mockito is trying to mock a private class. I don't know how to mock without changing the code. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am getting your problem by now. The problem is that you created untestable code. It is as simple as that:

```
class C {
  public B foo(parameters){
    A someA new A();
    return  someA.someMethod(parameters);
```

(please note: I reworked your example to use names that aren't so confusing for java programmers. You do not put "class" into the name of a class for example)

The problem with your code is that call to **new**. Simply spoken, that call makes it almost impossible to do reasonable unit testing for that method. The only reasonable answer here is: rework your production code, and introduce dependency injection, like

```
class C {
  private A someA;

  public C() { this(new A()); }
  C(A someA) { this.someA = someA; }

  public B foo(parameters){            
    return  someA.someMethod(parameters);
```

What you see there: there is an "internal" constructor that you can use to provided an A object. You use this constructor to give a mocked A to C; and all of a sudden, you can test the whole thing.

So, long story short:

a) I really advise to **change** this code; because it is badly designed, and simply not testable as of now

b) If you really can't do that; you might want to look if Powermock can help you here ... but beware: that is not a tool for beginners. It is powerful and dangerous on many levels.

In any case, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) ...

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you @GhostCat.