# Mockito.thenReturn(...) in not working

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Test Class

```
public class CollectionImplementationUnitTest {

  CollectionImplementation colImp;

  public void setup() throws Exception {
    ...
    colImp = Mockito.spy(new CollectionImplementation());
    ...
  }

  private String mockHistoryFromStrgyTable() {
    String value1 = "myValue";
    return value1;
  }

  @Test 
  public void testgetinfo (){
    ...
    Mockito.when(
      colImp.historyFromStrgyTable(
         Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString()
      )
    )
    .thenReturn(mockHistoryFromStrgyTable());

    CollectionsAccount Info = colImp.accountInfo(
      "string1","string2","string3", new IdentityAcc(), TableLst
    );

    //sometestmethods and asserts
  }
}
```

Class under Test

```
public class CollectionImplementation {
  ...
  @Override
  public CollectionsAccount accountInfo(("string1","string2","string3", new IdentityAcc(), TableLst)) {
      DetailsHelper helper = new (db2, "string",getmethod());
      return helper.accountInfo("string1","string2", new IdentityAcc(), TableLst); 
  }

  public String historyFromStrgyTable(){
    //contains a call to the data base
  }
}
```

**DetailsHelper**

```
public class DetailsHelper{
  public CollectionsAccount accountInfo((String string1,String string2,String string3, new IdentityAcc(), TableLst)){
  ...
  String paymentdetails = historyFromStrgyTable();  
  }
   public String historyFromStrgyTable(){
   //contains a call to the data base
   }
}
```

When I try to mock the data for the method HistoryFromStrgyTable() it is actually making a call to HistoryFromStrgyTable() instead of getting from mockHistoryFromStrgyTable().

My test cases are failing at this line

```
Mockito.when(col_Imp.HistoryFromStrgyTable(Mockito.anyString(),
  Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(  mockHistoryFromStrgyTable());
```

Can anyone help me with this. I don't understand what's wrong. I also changed the method mockHistoryFromStrgyTable() from private to public since mockito cannot mock private methods.

Comment: Hint: please study java coding style guidelines. Your code looks like you tried to basically violate each and any rule/convention on how variable/method names should look like ;-(

Comment: Hey @GhostCat Sorry about that. Do you want me to rename the classes, methods and variables. Or can you help me with doing that.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484623/create-a-junit-test-case-for-a-method-which-contains-a-call-to-another-method-fr?noredirect=1#comment64376341_38484623) with the same problem. My code looks some what like this. You tried to help me before also. Thanks man

Comment: Variable names should be camelCase. Then: no "_" in java names (except for ALL_UPPERCASE_CONSTANTS). Method names start lowerCase, too.

Comment: Hey I have changes my naming convention for methods and variables. Thanks for letting me know about the naming conventions.

Comment: The code that you provide is invalid Java code. Could you please check the code of `CollectionImplementation` and `DetailsHelper`.

Comment: The code is not complete @StefanBirkner. I have just written the methods that are being used for the test case testgetinfo(). Any suggestions?

Comment: @GhostCat I tried to change the code btw according to your suggestion but the its failing the tests. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594496/error-when-trying-to-write-a-dependency-injection). Please help me if you have time

Comment: @Random The signature of the `accountInfo` methods is not a valid java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're using a spy, not a mock.  Running the "real" method when you call it is exactly what Mockito spies are *supposed* to do.

To stub your spy, this is the syntax that you want to use.

```
Mockito.doReturn(mockHistoryFromStrgyTable()).when(colImp).
    historyFromStrgyTable(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString());
```

You can find more detail on this in [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480139).